# Could another celestial body make a bi-elliptic transfer significantly more efficient?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, delta-v, gravity-assist

Could using the gravity of another celestial body allow for something like a [bi-elliptic transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-elliptic_transfer)

that uses less delta-v than the theoretical "[infinite apogee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-elliptic_transfer#Example)" delta-v requirement?

If yes, has such a transfer ever actually been performed?

Comment: Do you mean a secondary celestial body in addition to the primary?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}\;$

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAS-22)?  In that case, a geosynchronous satellite stranded in a 51° inclination orbit used a very high apogee transfer with two lunar flybys at the high apogee to remove 40° of that inclination.

Comment: It would be like that. $\;$